How to expand the event of CWMP?
I do not konw how to expand event code and realize a informing package to ACS.
I hope to send a special informing package to ACS，How to add a special event code and what should I do to realize its function? Where can I find some information about it?
Thanks for every one who give answers.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
